# shortcut for my functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have hundreds of counter buttons and i found out how to do simple one in javascript.
But doing this function over and over again really boring, is there any way more easier than this?

Here is my code.

Javascript:

```
var cnt = 0;
    function add() {cnt++;set();}
    function sub() {cnt--;set();}
    function set() {myform.shesha.value = cnt;}
    function price() {myform.shesha1.value = cnt*.500;};

var cnt1 = 0;
    function add1() {cnt1++;set1();}
    function sub1() {cnt1--;set1();}
    function set1() {myform.shesha01.value = cnt1;}
    function price1() {myform.shesha11.value = cnt1*.750;};
```

HTML:

```
0<input type="button" value="shesha" onclick="add()" />&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<input type="input"  value="0" size="3" name="shesha" onblur="set();" />
<input type="button" value=" - " onclick="sub()" />
<input type="input"  value="0" size="3" name="shesha1" onblur="price();" /></br>

1<input type="button" value="anab " onclick="add1()" />&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<input type="input"  value="0" size="3" name="shesha01" onblur="set1();" />
<input type="button" value=" + " onclick="sub1()" />
<input type="input"  value="0" size="3" name="shesha11" onblur="price1();" /></br>`
```

Comment: Most definitely. Use arrays, exploit the DOM, blah blah blah. Plenty of options.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, Here is one:

```
cnt = []
```

Here, instead of having a bunch of variables, have an array and change the values in the array corresponding with your position.

. . .

```
onclick="add(1)"
```

. . .

```
function add(pos) {
    cnt[pos]++
}
```

Comment: sorry but i just learn javascript so if u can explain it more i will be thankful

Comment: yes i know but i dont know how to use thim in this example

Comment: cnt[0] is your first position in the array. You can imagine it as "cnt0". Instead of separate variables and functions to handle version of the same variable, you have one function using one variable, using positions in the array for each value. You pass the position to the function, which then performs the task.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="calc">
  <input type="button" class="add" value="add" />
  <input type="input" class="addVal" />
  <input type="button" class="sub" value="add" />
  <input type="input" class="subVal" />
</div>
```

JS: (presumes jQuery)

```
$('.add').click(function (e) {
  var add = $(this).parent().find('.addVal');
  add.val(add.val()++);
});
$('.sub').click(function (e) {
  var add = $(this).parent().find('.subVal');
  add.val(add.val()--);
});
```